# Creating SQL Views

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I insert a view column wherein my main table, the column does not exist but from the table that I will be joining values from, exists. Is there way I can do this?
What kind of JOIN functions can I use for this matter?

Comment: Are you talking about doing an `INSERT` against a view?  Or just creating a view with composite columns that are made up from other columns?

Comment: Creating a view with composite columns sir.

Comment: In that case, see my response below.

Comment: I don't get this, Are you simply trying to avoid writing a query with a join for some reason?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write the view just like a regular query and format it to return any columns (physical or created) that you like.  For example:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MyView AS 
SELECT a.*, b.*, CONCAT(a.id, b.id) AS CompositeId
FROM MyTable a
INNER JOIN MyTable2 b ON a.id = b.id
;
```

You can use any standard `JOIN` that you would use in a normal query.